# How do I install GeckoDriver if I am using Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, anaconda, geckodriver

I use anaconda navigator, and I am wondering where I put the GeckoDriver.exe file once I have downloaded it. I am using this for selenium. At the moment I have installed GeckoDriver and put it in the Anaconda folder, but I am getting the below error.

CODE:

`from selenium import webdriver`

ERROR:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'`

Comment: How did you install webdriver?